# c# OleDbDataAdapter excel missing last row

Tags: c#, excel

**GetExcelSheetNames:**

```
 static String[] GetExcelSheetNames(string excelFile, string extention)
 {
  OleDbConnection objConn = null;
  System.Data.DataTable dt = null;
  string filepath= excelFile;// +; excelFile;
  string Conn = "";

  if (extention == "xls")
  Conn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + filepath+ ";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;";
  else Conn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + filepath+ ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0";

try
{
 // Connection String. Change the excel file to the file you
 // will search.
 // Create connection object by using the preceding connection string.

  objConn = new OleDbConnection(Conn);
  // Open connection with the database.
  objConn.Open();
  // Get the data table containg the schema guid.
  dt = objConn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);

  if (dt == null)
  {
  return null;
  }

  String[] excelSheets = new String[dt.Rows.Count];
  int i = 0;

  // Add the sheet name to the string array.
  foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
  {
   excelSheets[i] = row["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
  i++;
  }

  return excelSheets;
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
     return null;
  }

  finally
  {
   // Clean up.
  if (objConn != null)
   {
   objConn.Close();
   objConn.Dispose();
   }

   if (dt != null)
   {
   dt.Dispose();
   }
   }
   }
```

**GetTable:**

```
private DataSet GetTable(string filepath, string extention)
{
string strConn;
if (extention == "xls")
{
strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + filepath + ";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;";
}
else
{
strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + filepath + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0";
}

 DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();

 OleDbDataAdapter myCommand = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [" + GetExcelSheetNames(filepath, extention)[0] + "]", strConn);
 myCommand.Fill(myDataSet, "ExcelInfo");


 if (myDataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
 {
 return myDataSet;
 }
 else return null;

 }
```

I export **excel data to datatable by using OleDbDataAdapter.**

My both method (above side) works however **last row is missing** .

Where i miss exactly how can i get all rows from excel ?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Possibly it thinks there is a header row? Try adding `;HDR=NO` to the connection string

Comment: may you please write connection string exactly what it will displayed

Comment: stick `;HDR=NO` on the end of your `Con` & `strConn` string

Comment: i get error as Could not find installable ISAM.

Comment: I am using this Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + filepath  + ";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;HDR=NO;"

Comment: No idea then, I would have thought it would be valid http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel/ try with a xlsx

Comment: Problem occurs because of special character in last row value how can i solve this problem ?